Formalizing the notion of gluing in topology
I am trying to completly formalise the intuitive idea of Gluing in topology. To give some context to this question, let me give an example of constructing the cylinder out of a square.

Constructing the cylinder out of quotient
Consider the rectangle $[0,1]^2$, we formalise gluing the left and right edge as quotienting the set by the minimal equivalence relation generated out of the relation $(0,t) \sim (0,1),\forall t \in I  $, then the resulting space $ [0,1]^2/\sim$ is the cylinder.
Constructing the cylinder out of the subspace topology
Consider the  set $S^1 \times [0,1]$, we give it the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Discussion
As seen in the above, on an intuitive level, it is pretty easy to see that cylinder should be the same whether it is constructed out of a quotient, or constructed out of the interval which itself has the subspace topology.
I have a  feeling that if we  quotient out any set $\mathbb{R^d}$ and give the quotiented set the quotient of the subspace topology, then that  be neccesarily homemorphic to some subset $\mathbb{R^n}$ with subspace topology. (A)
Now, do note that once we do the quotient of a set which is a subset of a bigger set, the resulting set is a set of equivalence classes, hence that is no longer a subset of the originally said bigger set.
I believe that the subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ that our quotient is homemorphic too should be the one seen as the result of the gluing action (its should be pretty clear that when we the ends of a paper together in 3D space, we get again something that gets again an induced sense of nearness i.e: topology from the ambient space that it exists in).
The question:
How do I prove (A) and further yet is there a natural construction of the subset that this the result of the quotient is homeomorphic too?

Convetion:
$$ S^1 = \{(x,y) | x^2 +y^2 =1\}$$

Every subspace of a metric space is metrizable. Is every quotient of a metric space metrizable?

Quotients of metric spaces are precisely the sequential spaces i.e. spaces for which topology can be described by sequences in some way, but if $x\in \overline{A}$ for example, that doesn't necessarily imply there is a sequence in $A$ converging to $x$.

As for your question, this basically follows from Whitehead's theorem which says that if $q:X\to Y$ is a quotient map and $Z$ is locally compact, then $q\times 1_Z$ is a quotient map. Since $q:[0, 1]\to S^1$ given by the exponential is a quotient map, so is $q\times 1_{[0, 1]}$.

Consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$x \sim y \iff \exists q \in \mathbb{Q}-\{0\} \; x=qy$$
That is, two reals are equivalent if they are rationally commensurable.
This is an interesting equivalence relation for many reasons. For example, picking a system of class representatives pretty much requires the axiom of choice. Nevertheless, endow $A=\mathbb{R}/\sim$ with the quotient topology.
Let us show the topology on $A$ is not Hausdorff. Let us examine the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which are open and appear as preimages (under the quotient map) of a subset of $A$.
Clearly, for a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to be a preimage, it must be closed under multiplication by nonzero rationals. We care about the preimage sets which are open, and the only open sets with this closure property are $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, and the empty set.
Take any pair of nonzero classes in $A$, say $[1]$ and $[\sqrt{2}]$. The only open neighborhoods of these classes are $A$ and $A-\{[0]\}$. Thus this space isn’t Hausdorff (it isn’t even $T_0$!), so it isn’t metrizable, so it isn’t attained as a subspace of a Euclidean space.
This is one of the main reasons, (at least according to my old professor), for the development of topology in the first place: metrics do not behave nicely with quotients, but the topology does.

Right. You may want to also add an example of a metrizable quotient of the Cantor set that does not embed in any $R^n$.

@MoisheKohan I am not familiar :) You can add an answer with that example, if you’d like.

"metrics do not behave nicely with quotients, but the topology does" I'd argue that topology also doesn't behave nicely with quotients, since to obtain any nice properties of $X/\sim$, either $X$ or $\sim$ has to be nice, or both. But the fact that we can describe when the quotients are nice, without having to start from scratch at the construction, is nice to have.

At least there is always a quotient topology. You always get a topology. You almost never get an inherited metric.
